# Can I automatically start and stop an azure website on a schedule?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

Even asking this question, I'm wondering how something so simple can be so difficult for me.  All I want to do is automate the stopping and starting of an Azure WebSite on a schedule.  At first, I looked at WebJobs, and created a powershell script that would stop the WebSite that used the stop-azurewebsite commandlet:

```
stop-azurewebsite [my site]
```

I then created a .cmd file to call it using powershell.exe to execute the powershell file

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File stopit.ps1
```

I created a WebJob to run the powershell command to stop the site, but it errored with a message saying:

```
stop-azurewebsite : The term 'stop-azurewebsite' is not recognized as the name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
```

So, I figured I'd go the REST API route.  I created a post request using fiddler and the proper management certificate to make a call to:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/[my subscription id]/services/WebSpaces/[webspace]/sites/[website name]/stop
```

Turns out, there is no 'stop' command.  There's 'restart', but that's obviously of no use in this situation.  So, all that said, what is a reasonable way to automate the stopping and subsequent (but much later) starting of an Azure WebSite on a specific time schedule?

UPDATE:

I've figured out how to issue the http request to stop the site using a PUT to

`https://management.core.windows.net/[my subscription id]/services/WebSpaces/[webspace]/sites/[website name]` with a body of `{"State":"Stopped"}`, but I still don't have an obvious way of 'PUT`ing' to this URL in a WebJob.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping Website from within a WebJob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620812/stopping-website-from-within-a-webjob)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620812/stopping-website-from-within-a-webjob

Comment: I tried to send a post request to the site endpoint with a body of `{"State":"Stopped"}` but get a message back saying `Web Service does not support Command . Only supported command(s) is Swap`.  Still can't stop this thing.

Comment: And why did you point to the same possible duplicate twice?

Comment: Alright, turns out I had to do a PUT, not a POST, but now how do run the http call in a WebJob?

Comment: Stopping website from it's own WebJob is not a good idea. Because WebJob runs as part of the site and if the site is shut-down, your WebJob is also inactive. This means that the site can't be started from WebJob. You'll need some other service running  to send requests to WebSites API

Comment: I have two WebSites.  =]

Comment: In that case have a look on Azure Management library: http://www.bradygaster.com/post/announcing-the-general-availability-of-the-microsoft-azure-management-libraries-for-net - C# API that allows you to work with Azure resources. I believe that includes web-sites. NB: I have not tried the library myself, only done API calls directly and it was a pain.

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Not a duplicate. The other question doesn't really stop the site. It just kills a process temporarily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Azure Automation, create a runbook and add the code below to get all 'Running' websites/webapps and shut them down.

```
# Get Websites/webapps
$websites = Get-AzureWebsite | where-object -FilterScript{$_.state -eq 'Running' }

# Stop each website
foreach -parallel ($website In $websites)
{
    $result = Stop-AzureWebsite $website.Name
    if($result)
    {
        Write-Output "- $($website.Name) did not shutdown successfully"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "+ $($website.Name) shutdown successfully"
    }
}
```

Publish the runbook and you should be able to schedule it straight in Azure Portal. Make sure your automated user is authenticated and your subscription selected in the runback and there should be no problems.

Similarly for starting up all websites/webapps just change 'Running' to 'Stopped' and 'Stop-AzureWebsite' to 'Start-AzureWebsite'.

Comment: Under ARM, you can modify this to Start-AzureRmWebApp and Stop-AzureRmWebApp

Comment: Just tried this, and it doesn't work - it seems you need to specify the subscription explicitly? Here's the output: ```Get-AzureWebsite : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default 

<subscriptionName> to set the default subscription.

At line:3 char:13

+ $websites = Get-AzureWebsite | where-object -FilterScript{$_.state -e ...

+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureWebsite], ApplicationException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Mift.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.GetAzureWebsiteCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Azure Automation. It lets you run Powershell scripts on a schedule and is a much easier way to run automation scripts that will start/stop/modify your sites.

Answer (score 0):

It's even easier now to do things on schedules using Azure Scheduler, especially in this situation. Stopping a website by simply making that API call with a scheduled job. Take a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/